# Suppressing zero padding in 'date' output

Tags: shell, date

I have an issue with `date` command's output.

When I run `echo $(date +"%b %d")`, the output is **Jan 06**. I want the output to be: **Jan 6**.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the hyphen. From the man-pages:

> By default, date pads numeric fields with zeroes.  The following optional  flags
>          may follow '%':

```
   -      (hyphen) do not pad the field
```

Also, you don't need the `echo`, just do this:
`date +"%b %-d"`